# MySQL INSERT query to avoid inserts

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table as follows:

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | userid | otherid |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 |      1 |       2 |
|  2 |      1 |       3 |
|  3 |      3 |       5 |
+----+--------+---------+
```

I don't want the pairing of `userid` and `otherid` to reappear in the table either way round. So for example the following inserts should not appear in the table:

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, otherid) VALUE ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO users (userid, otherid) VALUE ('1', '3');
INSERT INTO users (userid, otherid) VALUE ('3', '5');
```

What do I include in the INSERT to stop these inserts? Or do I have to do a separate SELECT query first? I know you can pair unique columns, but this won't reject the INSERTS above.

Answer (score 2):

if I understood your question, then what you are looking for is `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`.

you can add it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE(user_id,other_id);
```

in this case if an insert attempted to rewrite a condition where `user_id` and `other_id` exists mysql will throw an error.

Further reading [Mysql Unique](http://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=882)

Answer (score 0):

You could do another select in the function doing the insert or you could set up a trigger depending on what you want to happen. Do you want the insert to fail? An error to go back to user?

Triggers allow you to perform another call after something like an insert. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/

If the data is coming from a user you might want to also consider checking the data before it gets sent to the database. Validating it on the client side would save some time by reducing invalid calls.

Answer (score 0):

But that'll only stop:

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, otherid) VALUES ('1', '2');
```

I also what it to reject

```
INSERT INTO users (userid, otherid) VALUES ('2', '1');
```

Looking for something like

```
IF (userid = '1' AND otherid = '2') OR (userid = '2' AND otherid = '1') then fail otherwise input (userid = '1' AND otherid = '2')
```

Sorry not sure best way to explain

Answer (score 0):

Also, for performance reasons, you really don't want to refer to integer values as string literals if you have them defined as integers in the database.

It causes an unnecessary type conversion internally in MySQL which will become apparent at larger scale workloads.